# SQL SELECT multi-columns INTO multi-variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I'm converting SQL from Teradata to SQL Server

in Teradata, they have the format

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
INTO @variable1, @variable2
```

In SQL Server, I found

```
SET @variable1 = (
SELECT col1 
FROM table1
);
```

That only allows a single column/variable per statement. How to assign 2 or more variables using a single SELECT statement?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
SELECT @variable1 = col1, @variable2 = col2
FROM table1
```

Comment: Will doing this improve performance/speed compared to multiple SELECT's or is it the same?

Comment: The real answer is to test it and see for yourself. The informal answer is yes, of course, probably.

Answer (score 54):

```
SELECT @var = col1,
       @var2 = col2
FROM   Table
```

Here is some interesting information about SET / SELECT

> - SET is the ANSI standard for variable assignment, SELECT is not.
> - SET can only assign one variable at a time, SELECT can make multiple
>     assignments at once.
> - If assigning from a query, SET can only assign a scalar value. If the
>     query returns multiple values/rows
>     then SET will raise an error. SELECT
>     will assign one of the values to the
>     variable and hide the fact that
>     multiple values were returned (so
>     you'd likely never know why something
>     was going wrong elsewhere - have fun
>     troubleshooting that one)
> - When assigning from a query if there is no value returned then SET will
>     assign NULL, where SELECT will not
>     make the assignment at all (so the
>     variable will not be changed from it's
>     previous value)
> - As far as speed differences - there are no direct differences between SET
>     and SELECT. However SELECT's ability
>     to make multiple assignments in one
>     shot does give it a slight speed
>     advantage over SET.

Comment: that fourth bullet-point is a particularly important distinction since the behavior, to me at least, is not what you would expect; I recall finding this out the hard way when debugging a script that was assigning variables within a cursor with a select and I'll let you guess the rest...