# Get number of days,month,year from give two dates and type casting

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

I am trying to get the number of days,month and year from 2dates, but those are getting individual

```
DECLARE @datecount INT;
DECLARE @monthcount INT;
DECLARE @yearcount INT;

SELECT @datecount = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, usr.registrationdate, GETDATE())
                     FROM   users usr
                     WHERE  usr.userid = @UserId);

SELECT @monthcount = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, usr.registrationdate, GETDATE())
                      FROM   users usr
                      WHERE  usr.userid = @UserId);

SELECT @yearcount = (SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, usr.registrationdate, GETDATE())
                     FROM   users usr
                     WHERE  usr.userid = @UserId);
```

How to cast these 3 variables? Or how can I get this in one step?

```
no. of days / no. of months / no. of year
```

What I want the output is = `3:1:2` or `3 days / 1 month / 4 years`

Comment: Are you using SQL Server **or** MySQL, and which version #? The question tags include both ....

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, Does this answer your question? [SQL SELECT multi-columns INTO multi-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340775/sql-select-multi-columns-into-multi-variable)

Comment: sql server using @SOS

Comment: See the link above (ignore the reference to Teradata). It shows how to set multiple variables in the same statement, ie  `SELECT @datecount = Datediff(....), @monthcount = DateDiff(....), @yearcount = DateDiff(....) FROM  users ... `

Comment: Are you trying to show how long a user has been registered with your application? You'll not see a result of 3 days/1 month/4 years using `datediff` calculations like that. If a user's registration date were `2021-02-27`, for example, you would get a result of 365 days/12 months/1 years because each calculation is independent of the others.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Good spot.

Comment: DATEDIFF will give you numbers that may not be what you want.  For example 31-Dec-2020 to 1-Jan-2022 may yield 2 years, 13 months and 367 days. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days) for examples that would yield 1 years, 0 months and 1 day.

Comment: Also note that `DATEDIFF` counts date boundaries not whole years/months, so `DATEDIFF(year, '20211231', '20220101')` returns `1`

Answer (score 1):

A user-defined function can be useful for this.
Since the correct calculation for such an interval isn't as straight forward as one would assume.

The UDF below calculates the interval between 2 dates, with the output in the format of a JSON object.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetDateInterval
> (
>    @FromDate DATE, @ToDate DATE
> )
> RETURNS NVARCHAR(40)
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT;
>   DECLARE @tmpFrom DATE;
>   SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
>       - IIF(@ToDate < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate), @FromDate), 1, 0);
>   SET @tmpFrom = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
>   SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFrom, @ToDate)
>       - IIF(@ToDate < DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFrom, @ToDate), @tmpFrom), 1, 0);
>   SET @tmpFrom = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFrom)
>   SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFrom, @ToDate)
>       - IIF(@ToDate < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFrom, @ToDate), @tmpFrom), 1, 0);
>   RETURN CONCAT('{', '"years":', @Years, 
>                      ',"months":', @Months, 
>                      ',"days":', @Days, '}')
> END;
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @UserId INT = 42;
>
> SELECT CONCAT(days, ' days ', months, ' months ', years, ' years') AS DaysMonthsYears
> FROM users usr
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(dbo.fnGetDateInterval(usr.registrationdate, GETDATE())) 
>             WITH (years  INT '$.years',
>                   months INT '$.months', 
>                   days   INT '$.days') AS js
> WHERE usr.userid = @UserId;
> ```

> | DaysMonthsYears |
> | --- |
> | 3 days 1 months 4 years |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d09880deb84d18a6c9cc766edfc9835e)*